# How to use unescape() function inside JavaScript?

Tags: encoding, decoding, javascript

I have a JSP page in which I have JavaScript function that will be called when a link is clicked. Now, when the value reaches the JavaScript function, the apostrophe is encoded.

Example:

```
Name#039;s
```

Before # there is &, which originally should be:

```
Name's
```

I have used the `unescape()` decode function, but nothing seems to work. In the end, I had to delete the characters and add the apostrophe. Does anyone know a fix for this? Is it that JSP doesn't support encoding for `&`? When I was writing the same encode value in this page, it changed the symbol to the apostrophe, which is what I wanted in my code.

Comment: Not really relevant to your *core* question, but shouldn't plural of "Name" be "Names"?

Comment: I was just giving example nothing to do with grammar. For your sake let me change that to "Piskvor's". My problem is the apostrophe sign.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in Javascript function such as `unescape()`, `decodeURIComponent()` has nothing to do with the string you are working on, because the one you are looking to decode are HTML entites.

There are no HTML entites decoder available in Javascript, but since you are working with a browser, if the string is considered **safe**, you may do the following (in JQuery, for example)

```
var str = $('<p />').html(str).text();
```

It bascially insert the string as HTML to a `<p>` element and then extract the text within.

**Edit:** I just realize the JSP output you posted is not real HTML entities; To process the example given you should use the following, add `&` before every `#1234;` and make it `&#1234;`:

```
var str = $('<p />').html(str.replace(/\#(\d+)\;/g '&#$1;')).text();
```

Comment: +1 provided that the string is `Name&#039;s` and not `Name#039;s` this works

Comment: Here is small portion of my code `var splCharUrl="<c:out value="${result.url}"/>";`. Which is dynamically generated. So when apostrophe come in some value, `&#039;` replaces the value.